# Does SSISDB version Environments as well as Projects

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

It appears that SSISDB does not version Environments, even though they are at the same level as the Project. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: If you dig around in underlying the tables you'll see that the data model doesn't support environment versions. Nor does the UI.

Comment: That's what it looked like. Thanks for confirming.